# How to parse xml data into different format?

Tags: python, xml, parsing, xml-parsing

I have the following data in xml format.

```
 <UserStaging>
    <Staging>
      <Stage Type="Stage1" Start="0" />
      <Stage Type="Stage2" Start="50"/>
      <Stage Type="Stage3" Start="100" />
    </Staging>
 </UserStaging>
```

And I have to get it in this format:

```
<epoch><epoch_start>0</epoch_start<epoch_end>50</epoch_end><stage>NREM1</stage></epoch>   
<epoch><epoch_start>50</epoch_start<epoch_end>100</epoch_end<stage>NREM2</stage></epoch>
<epoch><epoch_start>100</epoch_start<epoch_end>9999</epoch_end<stage>NREM3</stage></epoch>
```

Where Stage1 is NREM1, Stage2 is NREM2 and so on and the "epoch_end" of an item is the "Start" of the following item.
The epoch time is variable.

How would I parse the xml data with for example python?
Is there any better way then using something like minidump to get the job done? 
What would the appropiate parsing commands look like?
Thanks for any reply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The usual tool for this kind of job is XSLT. In this case the job is easily done using XSLT 1.0, which is readily available for Python:

```
<xsl:stylesheet...

<xsl:template match="Stage">
  <epoch>
    <epoch_start>
      <xsl:value-of select="@Start"/>
    </epoch_start>
    <epoch_end>
      <xsl:variable name="next" select="following-sibling::*[1]"/>
      <xsl:choose>
         <xsl:when test="$next">
           <xsl:value-of select="$next/@Start"/>
         <xsl:when>
         <xsl:otherwise>9999</xsl:otherwise>
      </xsl:choose>
    </epoch_end>
    <stage>NREM<xsl:number/></stage>
  </epoch>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thanks. How would I replace only Stage1 with NREM1, Stage2 with NREM2 and Stage3 with NREM3? For exemple Type="Wake" should remain <stage>Wake</stage> and only every "Stage" should be replaced by "NREM"

Comment: I'm not going to get sucked into writing new increments of the code for each new increment of specification. If there are specific questions you need answering about new XSLT problems, ask new questions.

Answer (score 0):

xml.etree.ElementTree based solution. Can be implemented without the intermediate list of dicts which is used for debugging.

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

data = '''<UserStaging>
    <Staging>
      <Stage Type="Stage1" Start="0" />
      <Stage Type="Stage2" Start="50"/>
      <Stage Type="Stage3" Start="100" />
    </Staging>
 </UserStaging>'''

tree = ET.fromstring(data)
new_data = []
start = 0
for idx, stage in enumerate(tree.iter('Stage')):
    new_data.append({'start': stage.attrib['Start'],
                     'stage': 'NREM{}'.format(idx + 1)})
    if idx > 0:
        new_data[idx - 1]['end'] = stage.attrib['Start']

root = ET.Element("UserStaging")
for idx, entry in enumerate(new_data):
    epoch = ET.SubElement(root, "epoch")
    start = ET.SubElement(epoch, "epoch_start").text = entry['start']
    end = ET.SubElement(epoch, "epoch_end").text = entry['end'] if idx < len(new_data) - 1 else '9999'
    stage = ET.SubElement(epoch, "stage").text = entry['stage']

ET.dump(root)
```

Output:

```
<UserStaging>
   <epoch>
      <epoch_start>0</epoch_start>
      <epoch_end>50</epoch_end>
      <stage>NREM1</stage>
   </epoch>
   <epoch>
      <epoch_start>50</epoch_start>
      <epoch_end>100</epoch_end>
      <stage>NREM2</stage>
   </epoch>
   <epoch>
      <epoch_start>100</epoch_start>
      <epoch_end>9999</epoch_end>
      <stage>NREM3</stage>
   </epoch>
</UserStaging>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. You misunderstood me. I only want to replace Stage1 with NREM1 Stage2 with NREM2 and Stage3 with NREM3. Nothing more. For exemple Wake should remain Wake and REM should remain REM and there is NOT something like NREM4 & upwards.  If its possible i would also like to delete all lines with Movement in my data first before I parse it into the new format.